# Compare a sub-dictionary made from RF with a dictionary get from function in python

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary, robotframework

I want to compare a (sub) dictionary created from RobotFramework(RF) with a (big) dictionary got from Python function

```
${house_1_key}=    Set Variable    House 1
${list_values}=    Create List    A    n    ${empty}
${house_1_dict}=    create dictionary    ${house_1_key}=${list_values}
```

and dictionary from python like:

```
def get_sum_dict():
   ....
   total = {'House 1': ['A', 'n', ''], 'House 2':['','n',''],'House 3':['A','n','B']}
   return total
```

I tried to compare in python:

```
def compare_dict(sub_dict, total_dict):
  if sub_dict.items() <= total_dict.items():
     return True
  else:
     return False
```

but this was **FAIL**
I tried to compare from RF too:

```
Compare dictionary

      ${sub_dict}=  Convert To Dictionary  ${house_1_dict}
      ${total_dict}=  Run Keyword    get_sum
      ${total_dict}=  Convert To Dictionary  ${total_dict}
      Dictionary Should Contain Sub Dictionary   ${total_dict}   ${sub_dict}
```

But it **fails** too
and give back the error: **Following keys missing from the first dictionary: House 1**

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: In the python get_sum method, are you sure this is the returned value `['House 1': ['A', 'n', ''], 'House 2':['','n',''],...]`? Because as written, this is a list, not a dict. And, the RF keyword says in the failure message the python dict lacks the key "House 1", not the RF one, so check what are you getting from there.

Comment: @TodorMinakov: That's my typo, sorry. I'm sure it is a dictionary. 
I found that's also a failure message from RF https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/atest/testdata/standard_libraries/collections/dictionary.robot

Comment: Run `Log To Console` on the two variables, and see what you get printed - there may be a nuance in the values you're missing.

Comment: @TodorMinakov: Im using difido to record log I can see that return something like a dictionary but can't compare. But I assign a given dictionary and I can use method (comparison) to compare 2 those dictionaries.
Actuall, I used a method to get text from elements on web and return a list and cook it to a dictionary.

Comment: @TodorMinakov it seems the issue came from the function to get total_dictionary (from web) I can return and print out log but can't interact with it. example: I can't print the value in that total_dictionary['House 1'] <<< Value Error.
I tried to compare total_dictionary with the same given dictionary assigned myself
-> that's False

Comment: Well, there you go; you can check its actual type with `type($total_dictionary)` inside an `Evaluate` RF call (or in the python code).

Comment: @TodorMinakov I found that after get text from a website that actually return "House&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;" but not "House 1:" like I saw on difido report (after decoding from a report by html

Answer (score 0):

@TodorMinakov I found that after get text from a website that actually return "House  1  " but not "House 1:" like I saw on difido report (after decoding from a report by html